# Access same level data in Firebase using Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: This is the Screenshot of my Firebase database]

I want to access same level data with same key with the help of an iterator in my android app.
for an example - I want to retrieve all data of Validity Period that under 
serviceProvider > Mobitel > prePaidData 
The answer should be like this 
30 Days 
3 Days   
30 Days

Comment: Firebase always retrieves complete nodes. You cannot retrieve just a subset of the properties of each node. If you want to retrieve a list of just the validity values, you should in your database a list of just the validity values and load that.

Comment: Can I retrieve all sub nodes of a node. In here under prePaidData is it possible to retrieve all D199,D29,D299,D49 
and all their sub nodes.
How can I do that ?

Comment: Yes, you attach a listener to the data you want to read. Since this is a list of data, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#child-events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/serviceProvider/Mobitel/prePaidData");
ref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
        Log.d(TAG, dataSnapshot.getKey()+": "+dataSnapshot.getChild("Validity).getValue(String.class));
    }
    ...
```

For more information see the [section on reading from lists in the Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#child-events).

You can also query the data, for example to only get child nodes with a specific validity:

```
Query query = ref.orderByChild("Validity").equalTo("30 Days");
query.addChildEventListener(...
```